# Can't access javascript object's property with space

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am creating a JavaScript object and assigning a key which is dynamic. So there may be white space in the key. I can see the object **in the browser console** as follows,

```
{barTitle: 'Cash Flow', Cash Flow: 90254}
```

When I am looping through the object as follows,

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

I'm getting the following result,

```
barTitle Alrais
undefined
```

in browser console. How can I access the key in the above case (Please note that the object is dynamic and I don't know the key. In case if know the key then I can access it like `obj['Cash Flow']`) ?

Comment: Wrap the key of your object in '', like this: `'Cash Flow' : 90254`

Comment: You'll have to add a [mcve] to your question demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). There's no reason that the property should be undefined assuming the object is actually correctly created: https://jsfiddle.net/txxj7fhx/

Comment: @Patrick2607: The OP clearly said that's just what's showing in the browser console (not an actual object initializer).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was an exception thrown when you're trying to create the object. This should not be possible. oO

Comment: JS objects have keys and values. Keys are strings. So do it this way: `{"barTitle": "Cash Flow", "Cash Flow": 90254}`

Comment: @Werner: See my comment to Patrick.

Comment: @IvanKuckir: See my comment to Patrick (and Werner). Clearly, the object exists.

Comment: Actually I'm creating a grouped bar chart using d3 by referring this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051). Please not that instead of csv I'm consuming a json from rest api. In this case we can't predict the key.

Comment: @IvanKuckir: Side note: As of ES2015, not all property keys are strings. Some are Symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities here:

1. The "Cash Flow" property is inherited, or
2. The "Cash Flow" property is non-enumerable, or
3. Both. :-)

`Object.keys` only gives you the names of the *enumerable*, *own* properties of an object. Both inherited and non-enumerable ones are skipped.

You can use `for-in` to access all enumerable properties, including inherited ones:

```js
var proto = {"Cash Flow": 90254};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
obj.barTitle = 'Cash Flow';

// Doesn't show
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
console.log("----");

// Shows:
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to get **all** "own" properties of an object, including non-enumerable ones (this was new in [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) [2009]):

```js
var obj = {barTitle: "Cash Flow"};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "Cash Flow", {
  value: 90254
});

// Doesn't show
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
console.log("----");

// Shows:
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

If you need all properties with String names, including inherited non-enumerable ones, you can easily combine `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` with `Object.getPrototypeOf` (new in [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html)) to build a loop:

```js
var proto = {};
Object.defineProperty(proto, "Cash Flow", {
  value: 90254
});
var obj = Object.create(proto);
obj.barTitle = "Cash Flow";

// Doesn't show
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
console.log("----");

// Shows:
getAllPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});

function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  var names = Object.create(null);
  var p = obj;
  while (p && p !== Object.prototype) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p).forEach(function(name) {
     names[name] = true;
    });
    p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p);
  }
  return Object.keys(names);
}
```

In that, I've assumed you don't want to see the properties of `Object.prototype`, so we stop early if it's in the prototype chain of the object.

Also note that I've assumed you aren't interested in Symbol-named properties. If you are, use `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` to access them.